# This sliding code only works in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, cross-browser

This code shows 5 images that slide show one another.

They are all statically positioned and overlapping.

This way when they are toggled they show each other.

Works perfectly in firefox, but not in chrome or safari.

Could anyone figure why?

thanks in advance

```
var curPhoto = 6;
var scrollAmountUp = 0;
var scrollAmountDown = 0;


$(function(){
  //last scroll will always save the current scroll position value
  var CurrentScroll = 0;

   $(window).scroll(function(event){

    console.log('Event triggered');

      var NextScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

      if (NextScroll > CurrentScroll){
     //Scrolling Down
     scrollAmountUp = 0;
     scrollAmountDown++
     if(scrollAmountDown > 12){
        curPhoto--;

        console.log('Setting next photo:' + curPhoto);
        scrollAmountDown = 0;
        //Change Photo
        $('#swift-slider-' + curPhoto).slideToggle("900");
        if(curPhoto == 2){
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        }
    }
  }
  else {
    //Scrolling up
    scrollAmountDown = 0;
    scrollAmountUp++;
    if(scrollAmountUp > 12){

        console.log('Setting prev photo:' + curPhoto);
        scrollAmountUp = 0;
        //Change Photo
        $('#swift-slider-' + curPhoto).slideToggle("900");
        curPhoto++;
        if(curPhoto == 6){
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    }
  }
  //Updates current scroll position
  CurrentScroll = NextScroll;
```

});
});

Comment: What errors do you get in Chrome's console? Can you post a complete example so we can replicate the issue? A jsFiddle.net example is usually helpful.

Comment: No errors in the console:

visit: http://www.vertigo.meacloudserver.com to see it in action @j0891